# Python Pandas reads_csv skip first x and last y rows

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I think I may be missing something obvious here, but I am new to python and pandas. I am reading a large text file and only want to use rows in range(61,75496). I can skip the first 60 rows with

```
keywords = pd.read_csv('keywords.list', sep='\t', skiprows=60)
```

How can I only include the rows inbetween these values? There unfortunately is no *userows* parameter.

Is there something like

```
range(start, stop, start, stop)?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `nrows` argument to give the number of rows to read.

From [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) -

```
nrows : int, default None
Number of rows of file to read. Useful for reading pieces of large files
```

Code -

```
keywords = pd.read_csv('keywords.list', sep='\t', skiprows=60,nrows=75436) #Here 75436 is 75496 - 60
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realized nrows could be used in conjunction with skiprows like that.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can skip first few rows using

`skiprows = X`

where X is an integer. If there's a header, for example, a few rows into your file, you can also skip straight to the header using

`header = X`

Skip rows starting from the bottom of the file and counting upwards using

`skipfooter = X`

All together to set the header to row 3 (and skip the rows above) and ignore the bottom 4 rows: `pd.read_csv('path/or/url/to/file.csv', skiprows=3, skipfooter=4)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nrows` parameter

```
keywords = pd.read_csv('keywords.list', sep='\t', skiprows=60, nrows=(74596-60))
```