# Reading just range of rows from one csv file in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trining to read a csv file with Python and Pandas, but my file has a big size (1 GB) so I can't to read all datas.
By this web site I learned to use nrows to read rows from my file, for example read first 75 rows, but I can't to read a range of rows.

```
dts = pd.read_csv('C:\DtsPMU\dts.csv', dtype=float , nrows=75)
```

This link [Python Pandas reads_csv skip first x and last y rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660753/python-pandas-reads-csv-skip-first-x-and-last-y-rows) talks to use a code like this:

```
dts = pd.read_csv('C:\DtsPMU\dts.csv', dtype=float , skiprows=60, nrows=75)
```

Whit that code I'm try to read just range de rows (start in 60 to 75) but it doen't work.

How could I read range of rows from my csv file?

I'm use Python 3.6.5 and Pandas 0.23.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas read\_csv skip rows but keep header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325652/python-pandas-read-csv-skip-rows-but-keep-header) - assume your issue is that it's reading rows but skipping the header

Answer (score 4):

This code works fine

```
dts = pd.read_csv('C:\DtsPMU\dts.csv', dtype=float , skiprows=60, nrows=75)
```

The only problem is that it makes the row number 60 as the header, if you want the original header then use

names : array-like, default None
List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None. Duplicates in this list will cause a UserWarning to be issued.

For example: if your file has 3 columns, then

```
dts = pd.read_csv('C:\DtsPMU\dts.csv', dtype=float , skiprows=60, nrows=75, names=[0,1,2])
```

Comment: My file only has a one column
I use those code:
dts = pd.read_csv('C:\DtsPMU\dts.csv', dtype=float , skiprows=60, nrows=75, names=[0])
dts = pd.read_csv('C:\DtsPMU\dts.csv', dtype=float , skiprows=60, nrows=75, names=[1])

but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the output or error, whatever you are getting?